# Missing point in theorem enumeration

Tags: amsmath, enumerate

I use `llncs` (not article!) as `\documentclass` and the `ams` packages. And now numbering doesn't work. It *is* possible to simply use `\begin{theorem`} and number my theorems 1,2,..., but not by adding `\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}[section]` and `\begin{mytheorem}` as this yields things like 11,12,21,22 - without a dot. What I obviously prefer would be 1.1 or even 1.1.1. And a `\renewcommand` on theorem only leads to `TeX` being silly: Error, doesn't exist. Fine, then `\newcommand`:

> Error, does exist. (Either has to do with that TeX has something of a Zen master, or that \newtheorem has parameters :-) MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\begin{mytheorem} 
\end{mytheorem} 
\begin{theorem} 
\end{theorem} 
\section{bar}
\begin{mytheorem} 
\end{mytheorem} 
\begin{theorem} 
\end{theorem} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `llncs` class has its own method for defining theorem-like environments, using `\spnewtheorem`.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,envcountsect]{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%     \spnewtheorem{env_nam}{caption}[within]{cap_font}{body_font}
% or  \spnewtheorem{env_nam}[numbered_like]{caption}{cap_font}{body_font}
% or  \spnewtheorem*{env_nam}{caption}{cap_font}{body_font}

\spnewtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}[section]{\bfseries}{\itshape}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\begin{mytheorem}
Some text.
\end{mytheorem} 

\begin{theorem} 
Some text.
\end{theorem} 

\section{bar}

\begin{mytheorem} 
Some text.
\end{mytheorem} 

\begin{theorem} 
Some text.
\end{theorem} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, spares me a lot of search. Mind to shortly comment on the last two parameters? I strongly suppose that they set the theorem in bold and the text in italics. Correct? Also, I probably can define e.g. unnumbered stuff and other foobar exactly analogous to the theorem environment description on the Overleaf site?

Comment: @HaukeReddmann `cap_font` refers to the font to be used for the label (Theorem, in this case) and its number; `body_font` refers to the font to be used for the text. As far as I know, there is an implied `\normalfont` before each of them. You can also use `\spnewtheorem*{env_name}{caption}{cap_font}{body_font}` for unnumbered statements. I added the example syntax for the other types of call.