# Missing point in theorem number

Tags: numbering, sv-classes

I am required to use Springer's  `svjour3` as `\documentclass` and this leads to an ugly numbering: Using `\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}[section]` and `\begin{mytheorem}` this yields numbers like 11,12,21,22 - without a dot between the section number and the theorem number. I (and the referee) would like to have numbers like 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead.

The exact same problem with the `llncs` class was reported [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561351/missing-point-in-theorem-enumeration) but the solution given there - using `\spnewtheorem` instead of `\newtheorem` - doesn't work (error: "Missing `\begin{document}`")

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\begin{mytheorem} 
\end{mytheorem} 
\begin{theorem} 
\end{theorem} 
\section{bar}
\begin{mytheorem} 
\end{mytheorem} 
\begin{theorem} 
\end{theorem} 
\end{document}
```

I don't know how common the document class is, but here is [the class file](https://uni-duesseldorf.sciebo.de/s/MyLklus9g7TSdIu) provided by Springer

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you, Mensch! I have been reading some of your great answers before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `envcountsect` to true and use `\spnewtheorem`

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[envcountsect]{svjour3} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{amsmath}

\spnewtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}[section]{\bfseries}{\itshape}

\begin{document}
    \section{foo}
    \begin{mytheorem} 
    \end{mytheorem} 
    \begin{theorem} 
    \end{theorem} 
    \section{bar}
    \begin{mytheorem} 
    \end{mytheorem} 
    \begin{theorem} 
    \end{theorem} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reset the numbering to suit your needs via

```
\renewcommand{\themytheorem}{\thesection.\arabic{mytheorem}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{svjour3}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\themytheorem}{\thesection.\arabic{mytheorem}}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\begin{mytheorem} 
\end{mytheorem} 

\begin{theorem} 
\end{theorem} 

\section{bar}

\begin{mytheorem} 
\end{mytheorem} 

\begin{theorem} 
\end{theorem} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I threw a coin to decide which answer to accept and the other one won, but both solutions seem equally fine to me.